# Images do not appear correctly on MouseEvent in swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, mouselistener

[image: 3x3 check board]

I have a 3x3 check board-like image rendered on a JPanel which is added onto a JFrame. Then I have 9 more JPanels (1 on top of each square) and on click something needs to be drawn on the corresponding square. My problem is that it only works for the top-left square. The rest of the drawings seem to be drawn below the checkboard image. So if I comment out the part that loads the checkboard image,and click as if they were there then the drawings appear correctly. I get the same result with a layered pane. Absolute positioning is used and the coordinates seem to be correct since if I remove the checkboard image then the drawings appear where they should and the drawings do not occupy more than a square.
My code is structured as follows:

'main' class creates the frame and adds an instance of another class which extends JPanel and which also draws the checkboard image using paintComponent(Graphics g).
'main' class  has also 9 instances added of a class that extends JPanel and draws something on a mouse click using paintComponent(Graphics g). Each instance is placed on top of a square

Please note that because I was going to do it with just Rectangles I named the second class Rectangles but it is rectangualar JPanels not java Rectangle instances

Code:

```
public class Main3
{
    private JFrame frame=new JFrame("");
    private Rectangles rect00=new Rectangles(0,0,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect01=new Rectangles(136,0,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect02=new Rectangles(268,0,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect10=new Rectangles(0,136,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect11=new Rectangles(134,136,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect12=new Rectangles(269,137,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect20=new Rectangles(0,270,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect21=new Rectangles(136,269,129,129);
    private Rectangles rect22=new Rectangles(269,270,129,129);
    
    public void Display()
    {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(600,400); 
        sub inter=new sub();
        inter.setLayout(null);
        inter.setBounds(0,0,600,400);
        inter.setSize(600,400);
    
        rect00.setBounds(rect00.getX(),rect00.getY(),rect00.getWidth(),rect00.getHeight());
        rect01.setBounds(rect01.getX(),rect01.getY(),rect01.getWidth(),rect01.getHeight());
        rect02.setBounds(rect02.getX(),rect02.getY(),rect02.getWidth(),rect02.getHeight());
        rect10.setBounds(rect10.getX(),rect10.getY(),rect10.getWidth(),rect10.getHeight());
        rect11.setBounds(rect11.getX(),rect11.getY(),rect11.getWidth(),rect11.getHeight());
        rect12.setBounds(rect12.getX(),rect12.getY(),rect12.getWidth(),rect12.getHeight());
        rect20.setBounds(rect20.getX(),rect20.getY(),rect20.getWidth(),rect20.getHeight());
        rect21.setBounds(rect21.getX(),rect21.getY(),rect21.getWidth(),rect21.getHeight());
        rect22.setBounds(rect22.getX(),rect22.getY(),rect22.getWidth(),rect22.getHeight());
        rect00.setOpaque(false);
        rect01.setOpaque(false);
        rect02.setOpaque(false);
        rect10.setOpaque(false);
        rect11.setOpaque(false);
        rect12.setOpaque(false);
        rect20.setOpaque(false);
        rect21.setOpaque(false);
        rect22.setOpaque(false);
        
        inter.add(rect00);
        inter.add(rect01);
        inter.add(rect02);
        inter.add(rect10);
        inter.add(rect11);
        inter.add(rect12);
        inter.add(rect20);
        inter.add(rect21);
        inter.add(rect22);
        frame.add(inter);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new main().Display();
    }
    
    
    private class sub extends JPanel
    {
        
        private BufferedImage image;
        
        public sub ()
        {
             
            try
            {                 
                 image=ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
                        
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
             
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            return (new Dimension(600,400));
        }
        
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);   
        }
        
       
    }
}
```

This is the other class

```
public class Rectangles extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{

    private int Posx;
    private int Posy;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean selected=false;
    public Rectangles(int Posx,int Posy,int width,int height)
    {
          this.Posx=Posx;
          this.Posy=Posy;
          this.width=width;
          this.height=height;
          this.addMouseListener(this);     
    }
        
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        if(selected==true)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
               super.paintComponent(g2);
               g2.setColor(new Color(250, 235, 215));
               g2.drawRect(Posx,Posy,width,height);
               Graphics2D g3=(Graphics2D)g;
               g2.setColor(new Color(0,0,0));
               g3.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
               g3.drawLine(Posx,Posy,Posx+width,Posy+height);
               g3.drawLine(Posx+width,Posy,Posx,Posy+height);
           
        }   
        
    }
    
    public int getX()
    {
        return Posx;
    }
    
    public int getY()
    {
        return Posy;
    }
    
    
    public int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    
    
    public int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
    
    
    public void setSelected()
    {
        selected=true;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        
    }
         
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        
    }
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) 
    {
        
    }
         
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        selected=true;
        repaint();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help sooner.

Comment: In games that have moving images, perhaps `Absolute` would be used (in the case `JPanel`s are used to render the game images on screen) other than that use a `LayoutManager` especially in board games, if any animation/movement of the `JPanel` is needed use *glasspane*. Besides `Absolute` layout there is, `GridLayout`, `GridBagLayout`, `FlowLayout` and `BorderLayout` just to name of few of the popular, nest layout within other layouts to achieve effects a single layout cannot. See [here for more on LayoutMangers in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: OK. I will try that but if I remove the background image from Main3 I get the drawings correctly. Since the drawings are done using x,y boundaries, the positioning of the Panels is correct. I really want to know why only 1 drawing is shown on square 0,0 when click and nothing on other squares

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You dont honor the components *paint chain*.

As per java docs for `paintComponent(Graphics g)`:

> Further, if you do not invoker super's implementation you must honour
>   the opaque property, that is if this component is opaque, you must
>   completely fill in the background in a non-opaque color. If you do not
>   honor the opaque property you will likely see visual artifacts.

2) `super.paintComponent` would in most cases be the first call in the method.

3) But there is more, your cast to Graphics2D twice, that should not be done:

```
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
...
Graphics2D g3=(Graphics2D)g;
```

omit the `g3` its not needed you already have casted to a `Graphics2D` object

4) Another problem lies here in `sub` class. You do this in your main code:

```
inter.add(rect00);
inter.add(rect01);
...
```

but in `inter` which is your variable name for the instance of `sub` class you only have:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);   
}
```

Thus it will only draw a single image no matter how many rectangles you add!

Also dont do 
            `g2.drawLine(Posx, Posy, Posx + width, Posy + height);` rather 
            `g2.drawLine(0, 0, Posx + width, Posy + height);` as the JPanel has been added at co-ordinates `x` and `y` on its container, when you draw on the JPanel we want to start at the top left i.e 0,0, changing the value would move the image further down on its conatiner

See fixed code here:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("");
    private Rectangles rect00 = new Rectangles(0, 0, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect01 = new Rectangles(136, 0, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect02 = new Rectangles(268, 0, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect10 = new Rectangles(0, 136, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect11 = new Rectangles(134, 136, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect12 = new Rectangles(269, 137, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect20 = new Rectangles(0, 270, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect21 = new Rectangles(136, 269, 129, 129);
    private Rectangles rect22 = new Rectangles(269, 270, 129, 129);

    public void Display() {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.setSize(600, 400);
        sub inter = new sub();
        inter.setLayout(null);
        inter.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 400);
        inter.setSize(600, 400);

        rect00.setBounds(rect00.getX(), rect00.getY(), rect00.getWidth(), rect00.getHeight());
        rect01.setBounds(rect01.getX(), rect01.getY(), rect01.getWidth(), rect01.getHeight());
        rect02.setBounds(rect02.getX(), rect02.getY(), rect02.getWidth(), rect02.getHeight());
        rect10.setBounds(rect10.getX(), rect10.getY(), rect10.getWidth(), rect10.getHeight());
        rect11.setBounds(rect11.getX(), rect11.getY(), rect11.getWidth(), rect11.getHeight());
        rect12.setBounds(rect12.getX(), rect12.getY(), rect12.getWidth(), rect12.getHeight());
        rect20.setBounds(rect20.getX(), rect20.getY(), rect20.getWidth(), rect20.getHeight());
        rect21.setBounds(rect21.getX(), rect21.getY(), rect21.getWidth(), rect21.getHeight());
        rect22.setBounds(rect22.getX(), rect22.getY(), rect22.getWidth(), rect22.getHeight());
        rect00.setOpaque(false);
        rect01.setOpaque(false);
        rect02.setOpaque(false);
        rect10.setOpaque(false);
        rect11.setOpaque(false);
        rect12.setOpaque(false);
        rect20.setOpaque(false);
        rect21.setOpaque(false);
        rect22.setOpaque(false);

        inter.addPanel(rect00);
        inter.addPanel(rect01);
        inter.addPanel(rect02);
        inter.addPanel(rect10);
        inter.addPanel(rect11);
        inter.addPanel(rect12);
        inter.addPanel(rect20);
        inter.addPanel(rect21);
        inter.addPanel(rect22);
        frame.add(inter);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test().Display();
    }

    private class sub extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage image;
        private ArrayList<Rectangles> rects = new ArrayList<>();

        public sub() {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("c:/image.png"));

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return (new Dimension(600, 400));
        }

        void addPanel(Rectangles r) {
            rects.add(r);
            add(r);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for (Rectangles r : rects) {
                g.drawImage(image, r.getX(), r.getY(), null);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Rectangles extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    private int Posx;
    private int Posy;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public Rectangles(int Posx, int Posy, int width, int height) {
        this.Posx = Posx;
        this.Posy = Posy;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.addMouseListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (selected == true) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setColor(new Color(250, 235, 215));
            g2.drawRect(0,0, width, height);
            g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0));
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(20));
            g2.drawLine(0,0, width,height);
            g2.drawLine(getWidth(),0, 0, height);
        }

    }

    public int getX() {
        return Posx;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Posy;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setSelected() {
        selected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        selected = true;
        repaint();


    }
}
```

A few other pointers:

- Dont use `Absolute`/`Null` layout. A `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` would suit your needs fine. (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more.)
- Dont do `JFrame#setSize(...);` rather use Correct `LayoutManager` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` before setting it visible.
- Dont call `setSize` on your `Rectangles` instances, simply override `getPreferredSize` like you did with `sub` panel??
- No need for implementing `MouseListener`, just use `MouseAdapter` thus giving you the freedom to choose which methods to override and not just override all.
- [Have a read on Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) especailly [Event-Dispatch-Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)

Comment: But I do call super.paintComponent(Graphics g);

Comment: no you call it with the grahics2d object it should not, also it should be the first thing called unless you dont want those panels to paint their background, and why is tehre 2 graphics2D casts in one paintComponent... be see update

Comment: I'm getting the same glitch

Comment: Even without using Graphics 2D at all, I still get the glitch

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) is a short **compilable** example that demonstrates the behaviour...right now its throwing an exception, due to a missing image.jpg file...

Comment: @Anon855 see my updated post with fixed code, check sub class and how I added rects to the sub thats whats changed (and just fixed paintComponent of the Rectangles class)

Comment: @Anon855 pleasure, please see updated code! NB Dont forget within `addPanel(..)` method remember to call `add(r)` on the sub panel or the `JPanel` wont be added and thus no clicks will come through.

Comment: The problem with the crosses covered behind the image was not solved

Comment: the drawing of the Rectangle class is still done behind the image instead of on top

Comment: @Anon855 I see, well have you done all the other edits I suggested? If so please post that code so I can see whats wrong, right now its null layout thats giving problems IMO

Comment: BTW are you making a tic tac toe game?

Comment: I haven't started doing it with layout managers yet as I really want to find out why on the top left square lines are drawn successfully but not on others. Yes it is supposed to be a tick tack toe game. (I know I could use a grid layout with JButtons but I wanted something different). As soon as I find the reason I'll redo it with layout managers

Comment: @Anon855 okay well what if the reason is the null layout? and as for doing it differently you went for doing it in the worst possible way i.e using absolute, this is not a good practice, a layoutManager would make everything look much better and your code more elegant IMO. And no need for the JButtons JPanel is cool, Null layout not so much

Comment: Okay cool, well as I said *Adding: g.drawLine(0,270,129,129)...on the rectangle class draws a line on click for some reason as I wanted*... Null layout problem as I said. Anyhow I cannot be of further assistance null layout isnt my thing :)

Comment: @Anon855 Great choice, I would though also advise start a brand new project, I find editing old small applications harder than simply re-creating it with a fresh mind set

Comment: The problem was that the coordinates for drawing the lines in the rectangle class were relative to the whole Frame and I forgot that since each rectangle instance is a JPanel it starts at 0,0 so the boundaries for drawing each line should be 0,0,129,129 and 129,0, 0, 129. ANW, I  have redesigned it with Layout managers and it was easier!

Comment: @Anon855 +1 ooh yeah, I see that now, yes you are drawing in context of the placed JPanel thus we dont use x,y rather 0,0 unless we wanted to place image further down on its container, it completely alluded me! but as I said LayoutManager helps :)